# setting two arrays equal to each other in java

Tags: java, arrays, jvm

I am writing a program that has a double array called data.

My code so far is the following.

```
public class DataSet {
private double[] data;
private int dataSize;

public DataSet(){
    dataSize = 0;
    data = new double [10];
}

public void add(double x){
    if(dataSize>= data.length){
        double[] newData = new double[data.length*2];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
        newData=data;
        newData[dataSize]=x;
        dataSize++;
    }
    else{
        data[dataSize] = x;
        dataSize++;
    }
}
}
```

as you can see I am adding new values to the array using the add method.
However what I am unsure of is that when I do

```
newData=data;
```

Can I just make this change to the next line?

```
data[DataSize] = x;
```

The reason why I am asking is whether the by setting the two arrays equal to each other, whenever I call data, I am in fact calling newData.

Comment: You want to replace `data` with `newData` so you want `data = newData;`

Comment: System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
        newData=data;  explain this please

Comment: Yeah you are losing newData. Anyway it seems to me you are on your way to re-code ArrayList all over again. :)

Comment: I'm not sure you understand Java. Arrays don't have names and are not copied or overwritten with equal sign. You have variables (named) that may hold values (native types as int or long) or reference to objects (as arrays or anything that is not a native type value). The equal sign sets the value of the variable to the value of an expression being evaluated, in this case you are copying the reference to an object overwriting the previous value of the variable (not the values in the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've lost your created array (stored in `newData`) by assigning `newData=data;`

Replace

```
newData=data;
newData[dataSize]=x;
```

by

```
data = newData;
data[dataSize]=x;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to reassign `data`.  There is also some tools in the JVM which help you.

```
public void add(double x) {
    if (dataSize >= data.length)
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length * 2);
    data[dataSize++] = x;
}
```